# How to update Android SDK in m generator project?

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I had created m generator project, after I ran this project I got this error message how do i solve this problem

> Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I faced this problem this android sdk version problem.

you can use this line in terminal (project path):

$ cordova platforms remove android

$ cordova platforms add android